# How to do listview when it clicks it will direct in another xml file and display data?

Tags: android

public class AndroidListViewCursorAdaptorActivity extends Activity {

```
private BisdakDbAdapter dbHelper;
private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 

    dbHelper = new BisdakDbAdapter(this);
    dbHelper.open();

    //Clean all data
    dbHelper.deleteAllData();
    //Add some data
    dbHelper.insertData();

    //Generate ListView from SQLite Database
    displayListView();
        }

private void displayListView() {


    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllData();

    // The desired columns to be bound
    String[] columns = new String[] {
            BisdakDbAdapter.ENGLISH,
            BisdakDbAdapter.TAGALOG,
            BisdakDbAdapter.BISAYA,
            BisdakDbAdapter.DESCRIPTION
    };

    // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
    int[] to = new int[] { 
            R.id.english,
            //R.id.tagalog,
            //R.id.bisaya,
            //R.id.description,
    };

    // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data 
    //as well as the layout information

    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.translator_info, cursor, columns, to);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


**this portion is the onclick listener Items .......**  
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        *public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, 
                int position, long id) {
            // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

The data will display in the searchWord class something like this

```
             **Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "English: " + cursor.getString(1) + "\n" +
                        "Tagalog: " + cursor.getString(2) + "\n" + 
                        "Bisaya: " + cursor.getString(3) + "\n" + 
                        "Parts of Speech: " + cursor.getString(4),
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              Intent intent = new Intent(AndroidListViewCursorAdaptorActivity.this, searchWord.class);
              startActivity(intent);***                  

        }
    });
```

**My searchWord Class.  This is the next activity..**

public class searchWord extends Activity {

```
    private BisdakDbAdapter dbHelper;
    TextView textView1, textView2, textView3, textView4;
    ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.translator_info); 

    dbHelper = new BisdakDbAdapter(this);
    dbHelper.open();

}


    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, 
            int position, long id) {
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.english);
    textView1.setText(cursor.getString(1));
    textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tagalog);
    textView2.setText(cursor.getString(2));
    textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bisaya);
    textView3.setText(cursor.getString(3));
    textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
    textView4.setText(cursor.getString(4)); 

    };
```

}

**database adapter**

public class BisdakDbAdapter {

```
public static final String ROWID = "_id";
public static final String ALPHABET = "alphabet";
public static final String ENGLISH = "english";
public static final String DESCRIPTION = "description";
public static final String TAGALOG = "tagalog";
public static final String BISAYA = "bisaya";

private static final String TAG = "BisdakDbAdapter";
private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BisdakDb";
private static final String SQLITE_TABLE = "Words";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private final Context mCtx;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + SQLITE_TABLE + " (" +
                ROWID + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
                ENGLISH + "," +
                TAGALOG + "," +
                BISAYA + "," +
                DESCRIPTION + ","+ 
                ALPHABET + ","+
                " UNIQUE (" + ENGLISH +"));";

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.w(TAG, DATABASE_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SQLITE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

public BisdakDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.mCtx = ctx;
}

public BisdakDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    if (mDbHelper != null) {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }
}

public long createData(String alphabet, String english, 
        String description, String tagalog, String bisaya) {

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(ALPHABET, alphabet);
    initialValues.put(ENGLISH, english);
    initialValues.put(DESCRIPTION, description);
    initialValues.put(TAGALOG, tagalog);
    initialValues.put(BISAYA, bisaya);

    return mDb.insert(SQLITE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

public boolean deleteAllData() {

    int doneDelete = 0;
    doneDelete = mDb.delete(SQLITE_TABLE, null , null);
    Log.w(TAG, Integer.toString(doneDelete));
    return doneDelete > 0;

}

public Cursor fetchDataByName(String inputText) throws SQLException {
    Log.w(TAG, inputText);
    Cursor mCursor = null;
    if (inputText == null  ||  inputText.length () == 0)  {
        mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {ROWID,
                ENGLISH, TAGALOG, BISAYA, DESCRIPTION}, 
                null, null, null, null, null);

    }
    else {
        mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {ROWID,
                ENGLISH, TAGALOG, BISAYA, DESCRIPTION}, 
                ENGLISH + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null,
                null, null, null, null);
    }
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;

}

public Cursor fetchAllData() {

    Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {ROWID,
            ENGLISH, TAGALOG, BISAYA, DESCRIPTION}, 
            null, null, null, null, null);

    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}

public void insertData() {


    createData("a","abaca","noun","abaka","abaka");
    createData("a","abandon","verb","pabayaan","biyaan");
    createData("a","abbreviate","verb","paikliin","pagmubo");
    createData("a","abdomen","noun","tiyan","tiyan");

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AndroidListViewCursorAdaptorActivity.this, searchWord.class);
intent.putExtra("English", cursor.getString(1));
intent.putExtra("Tagalog", cursor.getString(2));
intent.putExtra("Bisaya", cursor.getString(3));
intent.putExtra("Parts of Speech", cursor.getString(4));
              startActivity(intent) ;
```

Then on

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.translator_info);

Intent i = getIntent(); 
textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.english);
textView1.setText(i.getStringExtra("English"));
textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tagalog);
textView2.setText(i.getStringExtra("Tagalog"));
textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bisaya);
textView3.setText(i.getStringExtra("Bisaya"));
textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
textView4.setText(i.getStringExtra("Parts of Speech")); 

dbHelper = new BisdakDbAdapter(this);
dbHelper.open();

}
```